# Set variable in npm script to env var from file

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I'd like to set a variable `FOO` (that is *not* in my .env file) in an npm script command to the value of the environment variable `BAR` (which *is* in the .env file).

For example, my `.env` file:

```
BAR=1234
```

And my package.json npm script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "try": env-cmd FOO=$BAR src/myScript.js
  }
}
```

...where I'd expect `FOO` to equal `1234`. But running `npm run try` throws the error:

```
spawn FOO= ENOENT
error Command failed with signal "SIGINT".
```

Footnote: I'm open to libraries other than env-cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for in your code or use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) in the NPM script command.

I doesn't make much sense to set an environment variable from an environment variable in the script command itself as you are assuming it is already set.  Running the npm script will not pick up anything from a `.env` file.